# Convert X-axis from date to hrs in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have a recording during 48 h of a probe of pressure of a recipient. After importing data from Excel I get two vars Time (class= "POSIXct" and Probe ('numeric').

```
'data.frame':   3647 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Date : POSIXct, format: "2020-01-15 17:34:02" "2020-01-15 17:34:42"...
$ probe: num  31.6 35.8 29.9 29.1 30.1...
```

I plot both vars using ggplot2 and geom_line and I get this graph
[image: Figure]

The X axis shows time (total 48 h)
However, when I try to format time by using:

```
library(hms) 
data$time<-as_hms(data$Date)
```

I got a  messy plot. I have tried different methods to convert 'data$time' to a different scales but I cannot manage this.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want it in hours, just subtract the initial time from all the other times to get the number of seconds from the start, then divide by 3600 to get hours: `data$time <- (data$time - data$time[1])/3600`

Comment: What "different scale" format do you want to show?

Comment: Hi Allan, Thanks a lot for your reply. I am a little bit confused  data$time[1] gives this value "16:50:05". If I substract  (data$time - data$time[1]) I get "time difference of 40 secs". This is the sampling rate, that is just fine. However, when I use data$time <- (data$time - data$time[1])/3600 i get many negative numbers. I assume that is because the recording druatin in about 48 h. If I do data$time[3647]-data$time[1] I get a Time difference of -26880 secs. Do you know how to fix this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved with `scale_x_datetime` by creating a breaks vector and labeling with a `date_labels` format string.

I have created a test data set, since there is none in the question.

```r
set.seed(2022)     # make the example reproducible

start <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-15 17:34:02")
end <- start + 48*60*60
Date <- seq(start, end, by = "15 mins")
probe  <- cumsum(rnorm(length(Date)))
data <- data.frame(Date, probe)

library(ggplot2)

breaks_start <- as.POSIXct(format(start, "%Y-%m-%d"))
breaks_end <- as.POSIXct(format(end + 24*60*60, "%Y-%m-%d"))

ggplot(data, aes(Date, probe)) +
  geom_line(color = "darkred", size = 1.2) +
  scale_x_datetime(
    breaks = seq(breaks_start, breaks_end, by = "12 hours"),
    date_labels = "%H:%M"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The code works perfectly fine. Many thanks!! I am new to Stack oveflow and I do not know how to prepare a good reprex question yet... Just, an addtional question. In my plot I get this format in X-axis "2020-01-16 12:00:00". How can I supress the date and leave only hours and min?

Comment: @Poggio Use `scale_x_datetime` with `date_labels = "%H:%M"`, like in my answer.

Comment: @Poggio welcome to stack overflow. If your problem was resolved, please accept the solution by clicking the tick to the left of the answer. Also consider upvoting helpful answers. Upvoting and accepting answers help others to easily find the solution to similar problems in future and provide a reward for helpful members of community.